# Laravel 5.2 Authentical ACL

Tags: laravel, admin, acl, laravel-5

Hi am trying to use [laravel-authentical acl](https://github.com/intrip/laravel-authentication-acl/blob/1.3/docs/index.md) for admin panel setup. 
All what i did is

1. downloaded laravel 5 by following official documentation of package
2. Followed instruction given by package
3. on step 7 i found this error

> [Cartalyst\Sentry\Groups\GroupExistsException] A group already exists
>   with name [superadmin], names must be unique for gro ups.

I didn't get this error in previous installation though.

Also, i found nothing when i hit
http://url_of_my_application/login

I am unable to set it up. I am new to Laravel. A help will be appericiated.

Comment: Sounds like the group `superadmin` is already created so don't create it just use it.

Comment: @TheAlpha yeah but i am unable to set up this package. Need a guide how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First **truncate** all the data from **groups** table then try to install package again , please check the **error** it says **group already exists** , It will work definitely .Also **ACL** creates group dynamically on installation , so take a database table backup first then truncate the table data. If you will change the group name from core files then it will take much time and not a standard way . Let **ACL** do its process itself don't customize files .Best of luck !!!